# Where is yahoo messenger desktop (windows)?

Tags: yahoo-messenger

I have been searching for the latest version of yahoo desktop messenger,but strangely all search leads me to https://messenger.yahoo.com. This page doesn't have any link for desktop version of yahoo. I can see only yahoo messenger mobile app OR yahoo web messenger. I would like to know whether Yahoo has stopped giving desktop messenger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahoo!_Messenger) there has been no active development on Yahoo Messenger for Windows since 2012.

> **Windows:** 11.5.0.228 / March 13, 2012; 3 years ago

It looks like Yahoo have parked the development of messenger indefinitely while allowing 3rd party access to the protocol and servers.

I did find this official [Tumblr](https://yahoomessenger.tumblr.com/post/134857091004/hello-its-me-i-was-wondering-if-after-all) post about a new development initiative for Yahoo Messenger but that is dated December 2015. It is mostly just marketing blurb and not a lot of technical information.

The direction they appear to be taking is mobile and web based only. This makes sense for Yahoo as they can develop a single code base for their client. Moving to a web-based client means it is platform agnostic.

So in summary, there is now no longer an official Yahoo Messenger for Windows or OSX.

Personally I use [Trillian](https://trillian.im) for accessing Yahoo Messenger.

---

**UPDATE 17/06/2016**

It appears that Yahoo are planning to re-release desktop versions soon. I received an email from Yahoo this morning with the following statement in it:

> **What about the Windows and Mac versions?**
>
> They are not available yet, but we're working on it! Sign up [here](https://www.getfeedback.com/r/n9JUXsCu/q/1) to be notified of any updates. In the meantime, we encourage you to try the browser version at https://messenger.yahoo.com.

Comment: Thanks Burgi for this update.  I thought, after the announcement of yahoo to discontinue desktop yahoo messenger, there will be a huge hue and cry from the community. The web based messenger does not have features like web cam etc. Not all will like to chat on their mobile phones. So, desktop messenger offered a lot, which they have killed. Hope they bring it back.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this link for the yahoo messenger latest version.
http://yahoo-messenger.en.softonic.com/

Comment: That answers my question partially.  I know that messenger is available from softsonic, but why is the download not available on yahoo's server? Has yahoo stopped giving yahoo messenger for window desktop?

Comment: We are not yahoo any answer as to the reason it's not on Yahoo's website would be pure speculation on our part